# Codility lesson 1 TapeEquilibrium for java shows 33%

Tags: java

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int lengthOfArray = A.length;
    int tempArray[] = new int[lengthOfArray];
    System.arraycopy(A, 1, tempArray, 0,lengthOfArray-1);
    int head = A[0];
    int tail = 0;
    for(int arrElm : tempArray){
        tail += Math.abs(arrElm);
    }
    double minDifference = Math.abs(tail-head);
    for(int i = 1; i<lengthOfArray; i++){
        head += A[i];
        tail -= A[i];
        double tempDifference = Math.abs(tail - head);
        if(tempDifference < minDifference){
            minDifference = tempDifference;
        }
    }
    return (int) minDifference;
}
```

**Note: The above solution is showing only 33%, for negative data it's failing in correctness.**

I am not sure where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: `A[0] = 3
  A[1] = 1
  A[2] = 2
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code. I think your problem is when you are calculating this:

```
for(int arrElm : tempArray){
    tail += Math.abs(arrElm);
}
```

You shouldn't use the absolute value. So it should be:

```
tail +=arrElm
```

Besides this, another problem I saw is the for loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i<lengthOfArray; i++)
```

should be:

```
for(int i = 1; i<lengthOfArray-1; i++)
```

Otherwise the input [-1, 1] will return 0 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use of **Math.abs** giving you incorrect results; Input values should be used as is.

Math.abs - Returns the absolute value of an int value. If the argument is not negative, the argument is returned. If the argument is negative, the negation of the argument is returned.

Again, there is no need of using **System.arraycopy**. PFB corrected code:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int lengthOfArray = A.length;
    int head = A[0], tail = 0;

    for (int j = 1; j < lengthOfArray; j++)
        tail += A[j];

    double minDifference = Math.abs(tail - head);

    for (int i = 1; i < lengthOfArray; i++) {
        head += A[i];
        tail -= A[i];
        double tempDifference = Math.abs(tail - head);

        if (tempDifference < minDifference)
            minDifference = tempDifference;
    }
    return (int) minDifference;
}
```

Comment: No this solution is not helping. It gives me 25% in codility

Comment: Could you check again and let me know for which input...its giving incorrect o/p.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the task description, you'll find that elements in the A array are within range [-1000,1000], so you can use ***short*** instead of ***int*** for the purpose and save the space and processing power.

***Short*** can keep values within [-32768,32767] while ***int*** within [-2147483648,2147483647]. Both are way too big for values in array A so why use the needlessly bigger type? Numbers kept as short not only take half the memory space (16 bits compared to 32bits) but also require less processing power to operate on.

Since you have to go through the whole A array of int initially to get the sum of its elements anyways, you can map it to an array of short in the same loop.

And there's no need to use double for the tempDifference - all elements of the A array are integers. It's not possible to get a floating point number out of subtraction or addition of two integers.

This gets 100%/100% result:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    short[] shortA=new short[A.length]; //this will hold a copy of int[] A, but instead of integer it uses short
    int sum1stSlice=A[0],               //sum of first slice of the A array, initially it contains just the first element
        sum2ndSlice=0,                  //we'll get a sum of the remaining part of the A array later
        minimalDifference,
        difference;
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){        //iterating throug the whole A array for the first time
        shortA[i]=(short)A[i];          //mapping values in A kept as int to values in our own array, keeping them as short
        sum2ndSlice+=shortA[i];         //two birds with one stone - we use the same iteration for getting the sum of all elements
    }
    sum2ndSlice-=sum1stSlice;           //sum of all elements but the first one - now it's truly sum2ndSlice
    minimalDifference=Math.abs(sum1stSlice-sum2ndSlice);    //initially the minimal difference will be the current difference
    for(int i=1;i<shortA.length-1;i++){         //iterating through all elements of our newly created, more compact version of array A: shortA
        sum1stSlice+=shortA[i];                 //moving one element to the sum of first slice
        sum2ndSlice-=shortA[i];                 //removing that element from the sum of second slice
        difference=Math.abs(sum1stSlice-sum2ndSlice);       //getting the difference between the sums of these slices
        if(difference<minimalDifference)minimalDifference=difference;   //checking for the new minimum
    }
    return minimalDifference;
}
```

Also, as noted above:

```
for(int arrElm : tempArray){
        tail += Math.abs(arrElm);
    }
```

Is incorrect, as the task description clearly states that the elements can be nagative, within [-1000,1000] and using Math.abs will get you additive inverses of everything within [-1000,0].